Header for AWS Cloud 9 web scraping
I created a script for web scraping in my personal desktop. So, I was migrating it to a Linux AWS Cloud 9 (my desktop is Windows), but it returns error 403. Is it because Headers configuration?
headers = {
    "authority": "www.reclameaqui.com.br",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "accept-language": "pt-BR,pt;q=0.9",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "origin": "https://www.reclameaqui.com.br",
    "referer": "https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Not.A/Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
}

if response.status_code == 200:
   html_content = response.content
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
else:
   print(response.status_code)


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

you could  create minimal reproducible example so we could copy and test it

you should check also print(  response.content ) - maybe it has some useful information. Maybe it sends Captcha or maybe it send warning because it doesn't like your IP.

BTW: if you want to scrape www.reclameaqui.com.br then first you should check if it works in browser when you turn off JavaScript. I checked it and it seems it needs JavaScript to add some values - but requests and BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript - so all this code may be useless to get some elements. It may need to use Selenium  to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.
